# PHPstan rules to migrate from 7.0 to 7.2

Tags: phpstan

Im wondering if there are any existing PHPStan rules / ruleset which checks a codebase for BC breaking changes when wanting to migrate from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

PHPStan makes an analysis of your code, not a check for PHP code compatibility.

Better tools for such migration is PHP CS Fixer: see this [[Meta] PHP 7.2 features](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/2907)

Comment: By analysing the code it can check for BC breaking changes. For example, giving not enough parameters to a function. But i will check out that link you send. Thanks!

Comment: That's true. The difference is rather tell vs. do.